# What is the correct type for splitting an object in two complimentary objects in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

What is the correct Typescript type for splitting an object into two sub-objects, each containing complimentary keys, so for example, an object of the form

```
{x: "x", y: "y", z:"z"}
```

should be split up in an object

```
{ a: {x: "x"}, b: {y: "y", z:"z"}}.
```

What is the type of this object for general Records?

I have tried this, but it gives me an error:

```
type Split<Union extends Record<string, string | number>>= <A extends Partial<Union>>() => {
    a: A,
    b: Omit<Union, keyof A>
};

type SpecificUnion = {
    x: string
    y: number
    z: string
}

const split: Split<SpecificUnion> = () => {
    return {
        a: { x: "x" },
        b: { y: "y", z: "z"}
}}
```

I get the error

```
Type '() => { a: { x: string; }; b: { y: string; z: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Split<SpecificUnion>'.
  Call signature return types '{ a: { x: string; }; b: { y: string; z: string; }; }' and '{ a: A; b: Omit<SpecificUnion, keyof A>; }' are incompatible.
    The types of 'a' are incompatible between these types.
      Type '{ x: string; }' is not assignable to type 'A'.
        '{ x: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'A', but 'A' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Partial<SpecificUnion>'.
```

This error seems to contradict itself because it says "'{ x: string; }' is not assignable to type 'A'" and "'{ x: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'A'".

Comment: The error message says that `A extends Partial<Union>` can be `{ x: string }` but it can be `{ y: number }` as well. Or `{ x: string; y: number}`. For different values of `A`you get different definitions for `Split<SpecificUnion>` but `Split<Union>` is not parameterized by `A`, therefore it should not depend on the definition of `A`.

Comment: `"y"` is not a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says that `A extends Partial<Union>` can be `{ x: string }` but it can be `{ y: number }` as well. Or `{ x: string; y: number }`.

For different values of `A` you get different definitions for `Split<SpecificUnion>` but `Split<Union>` is not parameterized by `A`, therefore it should not depend on the definition of `A`.

The solution is to let `A` be a parameter of type `Split`:

```js
type Split<Union extends Record<string, string | number>, A extends Partial<Union>> = () => {
    a: A,
    b: Omit<Union, keyof A>
};

type SpecificUnion = {
    x: string
    y: number
    z: string
}

const split1: Split<SpecificUnion, { x: string }> = () => {
    return {
        a: { x: "x" },
        b: { y: 3, z: "z" },
    }
}

const split2: Split<SpecificUnion, { x: string, y: number }> = () => {
    return {
        a: { x: "x", y: 3 },
        b: { z: "z" },
    }
}
```

Check it [online](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAymA2BLYAeAqgO0Qew1CAHsBBgCYDOUAShAMbYBOpK5wDiGA5gDRSvtcoAHygYArgFsARhAYA+XgEF8REhSgAFAIYNgiLfHRZccuVAC8UABQBKC2YDeAKCiuoWgFxRF3F26leAPISyEY4GLwA1hAg2ABm3nJOAL4A3E5OoJCwkLSIcYi0mOEWUM5uUARe-Bycfq4gXuLSsvVQAF7VbLUpGVnQAMKlwaFwdPmFxbi8AOQEM0lO9BisfAjIAIxecEioY3kFRcYRZZVdApxQyWaWtvZlbQwQwGIMeOUVbp6nVVAARAQ-ldfJ9-F4HFBGlAAMy8Tr-dpA5K+ZLJDLLVbkdbAABM22xKH2EyO4V4EN+NS4vChzRkDCuN2sdnMjkez1e7zaFW+5K8AL+1K80OBXLBp3hf0RItRTiAA).

Comment: Thanks @axiac, what do you mean with the last statement? It seems like split3 is just untyped. How can the compiler infer if it is really an instance of a split for some union?

Comment: Oops, you are right. I don't know what I was thinking about when I wrote that part. I removed it from the answer.